# Book where adults are turning into monsters like zombies, and a boy takes refuge with other children in a school classroom

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, horror, zombie

I remember reading a book about two years ago, but I can't remember the name. It's a young adult book, and I know there are at least two books in the series.

One of the main characters is a boy whose name I don't know; he might be telling the story, I'm not sure. I think he has an older brother. There are monsters that are like zombies; they might be all the adults over 18.

The main setting is a school with other children and they have to block the doors and windows. He also sees his teachers who have become monsters. I don't really remember anything else, so if you have heard of this, can you please tell me?

Answer (score 4):

Could this be ***[Convoy of Carnage](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/34108605-convoy-of-carnage)*** (2017) by David A. Simpson, the first book in the *[Zombie Road](https://www.goodreads.com/series/221369-zombie-road)* series...?

From Goodreads:

> The first book in a thrilling new series.
> The people that tried to kill the world were fiendishly clever.
> **After decades of planning, the contagion was unleashed and overnight hundreds of millions died and came back as rampaging, undead monsters.** The living that had been lucky enough to survive the first day of carnage, lucky enough to be in the right place and lucky enough that some of them had the skills they needed, soon found out there was much more to worry about than just zombies.
>
> In the high desert on the outskirts of Reno, there is an old truck stop frequented by a mix of hard caliber truckers, day tourists, musicians and travelers. They have survived the chaotic first hours of contact with the undead and now must make their way across the country to a location they believe is safe. Zombies are only the beginning of their troubles as they try to cover the thousands of miles of open road with their hastily armored 18-wheelers. Gunny, a long haul trucker doing one of the few jobs available to him as a disgraced soldier, is unwillingly saddled with the job of getting these survivors to the safe zone. With a motley crew of truck drivers, college kids, veterans, a drug dealer and a rock star, they are racing the clock to make it before time runs out. The last text he had received from his wife before the cell towers went down told him she was trapped in a high-rise in downtown Atlanta and **their son was in detention, stranded in the basement of the school he attended.** Gunny just wanted to drop the hammer, steal some guns and blast his way in to rescue them but duty called. He had to get these people to safety first, then he could recruit the best of this crew to help him save his family. If they survived the journey.

Comment: @Leah - If anyone correctly identifies the book you're looking for, please mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. Or if the only answers posted are incorrect, please indicate that with a comment so we know to keep looking. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are thinking of the book, "The Rains" by Gregg Hurwitz.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to explain why you think this might be the correct book, i.e. the ways in which it matches the one described in the question. It'd help the rest of us to decide how likely this answer is to be correct, and whether we should therefore upvote it or not.